# Get the object array that contains unique values based on condition from an existing object array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am having an array of objects containing information about my products as below:

```
var products = [{ProductID: 1, Product Name:"Toy Car", Price: 250},
        {ProductID: 2, Product Name:"TriCycle", Price: 1250},
        {ProductID: 1, Product Name:"Toy Car", Price: 450},
        {ProductID: 3, Product Name:"Feeding Chair", Price: 1700},
        {ProductID: 3, Product Name:"Feeding Chair", Price: 2200},
        {ProductID: 1, Product Name:"Toy Car", Price: 500},
        {ProductID: 2, Product Name:"Tricycle", Price: 1020},
        {ProductID: 4, Product Name:"Baby swing", Price: 430},
        {ProductID: 4, Product Name:"Baby swing", Price: 550}]
```

Now I want to get the Array of object that contains unique product Name having the lowest price as follows

```
var UniqueProducts = [{ProductID: 1, Product Name:"Toy Car", Price: 250},
            {ProductID: 2, Product Name:"TriCycle", Price: 1020},
            {ProductID: 3, Product Name:"Feeding Chair", Price: 1700},
            {ProductID: 4, Product Name:"Baby swing", Price: 430}]
```

Is there any direct Array functionality that can achieve this result as i dont want to parse each and every item in the array(using for loop)?

Answer (score 0):

There is no auto way to do what you want.  It pretty much takes brute force looping and comparison.  There are probably some libraries out there that have something to help and you could use built-in looping, but the plain JS that works in any browser isn't that complicated:

```
var products = [{ProductID: 1, "Product Name":"Toy Car", Price: 250},
        {ProductID: 2, "Product Name":"TriCycle", Price: 1250},
        {ProductID: 1, "Product Name":"Toy Car", Price: 450},
        {ProductID: 3, "Product Name":"Feeding Chair", Price: 1700},
        {ProductID: 3, "Product Name":"Feeding Chair", Price: 2200},
        {ProductID: 1, "Product Name":"Toy Car", Price: 500},
        {ProductID: 2, "Product Name":"TriCycle", Price: 1020},
        {ProductID: 4, "Product Name":"Baby swing", Price: 430},
        {ProductID: 4, "Product Name":"Baby swing", Price: 550}]

// gather all the unique products and lowest price
var lowestProduct = {};
for (var i=0; i < products.length; i++){
    var item = products[i];
    var name = item["Product Name"];
    if (!lowestProduct[name] || item.Price < lowestProduct[name].Price) {
        lowestProduct[name] = item;
    }
}

// create output data structure
var uniqueProducts = [];
for (var product in lowestProduct) {
    uniqueProducts.push(lowestProduct[product]);
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Ks58N/

FYI, I had to fix your products data structure to be legal JS by putting quotes around `"Product Name"` and fixing both instances of `"TriCycle"` to use the same capitalization.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UnderscoreJs](http://underscorejs.org) library - it provides a lot of helpfull function to work with collections(arrays). Using this library your solution will look like:

```
var products = [{ ProductID: 1, ProductName: "Toy Car", Price: 250 },
        { ProductID: 2, ProductName: "TriCycle", Price: 1250 },
        { ProductID: 1, ProductName: "Toy Car", Price: 450 },
        { ProductID: 3, ProductName: "Feeding Chair", Price: 1700 },
        { ProductID: 3, ProductName: "Feeding Chair", Price: 2200 },
        { ProductID: 1, ProductName: "Toy Car", Price: 500 },
        { ProductID: 2, ProductName: "Tricycle", Price: 1020 },
        { ProductID: 4, ProductName: "Baby swing", Price: 430 },
        { ProductID: 4, ProductName: "Baby swing", Price: 550 }];

//group by name
var groupedProducts = _.groupBy(products,
    function (product) {
        return product.ProductName.toLowerCase();
    });

var result = [], i=0;

//foreach group find element with min price.
_.each(groupedProducts,function (group) {
    result[i] = _.min(group, function (product) { return product.Price; });
    i++;
});

console.log(result);
```

[**JsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nicolai8/xxd4P/3/)